# Being in multiple Slack teams simultaneously

Tags: macos

1. I want to see notifications from two (or more) Slack teams.
   Can the Mac OS Slack client be launched twice?
2. Can I specify two teams in IFTTT Slack channel properties?
   Since I want to send Weather notifications to two different teams.
   Or maybe this is solvable only through using multiple (different emails) IFTTT accounts?

Comment: I think nowadays [Adi's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/836570/being-in-multiple-slack-teams-simultaneously/872452#872452) should be the accepted one.

Comment: Although they're both Slack questions, these two questions are about two distinct things. It would help people find the questions, and help you choose the best answer, if they were two separate questions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While each team account is separate, you can use the same email address to sign up for multiple teams.

You can be signed in to multiple Slack teams at once, and when you sign out of one team, it doesn't affect your accounts on other teams.

--- Mac desktop app ---

The Mac desktop app (version 1.0+) allows you to seamlessly navigate between your teams.

Locate the Team Menu — click the down arrow next to your current team's name.
Select Sign in to another team.
Enter an existing team's domain and click Continue, or Create a new team.
Enter your email address and password to sign in.
Once you're signed in to more than one Slack team, the Mac app will display your team icons on the left-hand side so you can switch between them easily. (Owners and admins can customize this icon for their team: Uploading a team icon.)

--- Web ---

If you're using Slack on the web, you can open each team in a separate browser tab — just enter teamname.slack.com in your browser's address bar to sign in. You'll be able to receive desktop notifications for all teams simultaneously.

If you prefer to use a single browser tab, visit the Team Menu and select Sign in to another team. You'll then be able to switch between teams from this menu.

--- iOS & Android apps ---

Sign in to an additional team at any time via the Switch Team or Settings screens — use the menu button in the top right corner or swipe left. On iOS, you can also triple-swipe to switch 
quickly!

https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201405046-Joining-multiple-Slack-teams

Comment: is this still how it is? this restriction is a pretty massive issue with slack in my books

Comment: It's different in version 2.0 of the Mac app. https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201405046-Signing-in-to-multiple-Slack-teams

Comment: Something has changed. Slack used to show the teams icon in the nav bar, but now its separate windows. Can we choose to change it back?

Comment: Note: one hack to run each team in their own app is to generate your own apps from the Slack web app using Fluid (see my answer for more detail and a caveat or two https://superuser.com/a/1308124/52878)

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to open more than one instance of the app, FYI. While it's running, you can go to Window -> Sign in to another team...
And sign in to another team simultaneously. I presently have 4 teams open in one slack window.
Its really nice because it adds a new ~50px sidebar on the left displaying your teams in any order you choose (you can drag them around).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the first question. To be clear, though, it's Window→Sign Into Another _Workspace_ in the current Linux version (3.2.1) of Slack.

Comment: Yeah it may have changed since I wrote this since that was 3 years ago now :)

Comment: Does this only work for the desktop app? How about for multiple workspaces and not multiple teams?

Comment: No, you can sign into another workspace in the web version as well (I'm looking at it as I write this). Not sure what you mean by multiple workspaces vs multiple teams.

Answer (score 8):

You can run `open -n /Applications/Slack.app` to open another instance.

There is a Beta to run in a single version of the native app which is [available here](https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/06bd6493684f65a3b8f47aca92c9006e), but I take no responsibility for its security :)

Comment: How can I be sure, that two instances launched in that way (`open -n`) share their files without conflicts?

Comment: I guess the first part is that Slack is a SaaS hosted on their service, not on your computer. Application information is stored by team, so different teams wouldn't cause conflict. It's also good to know that [Slack recommends this workaround](https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201405046-Can-I-belong-to-more-than-one-Slack-team-) until the next version comes out w/multiple team support.

Comment: Sadly, this technique doesn't work anymore. The additional spawned instance of Slack opens, sets focus on the existing instance, and closes. :(

Comment: Not sure whether anything changed since @JakeRobb's posting, but this technique works for me with Slack 3.3.7 on macOS 10.13.6.

Comment: @mhucka I just tried it. Same version combination. When I execute that line in Terminal, it briefly opens a new instance of Slack, but it closes immediately and brings focus to the existing open instance. What, exactly, happens when you do it?

Comment: @JakeRobb I get 2 instances of Slack running :-). Both work normally, as far as I can tell. I tried repeating it just now and it is definitely a consistent result in my case. I can't explain why we would see different behavior for the same os and Slack versions. Perhaps there's some obscure macOS `defaults` setting that one of us changed? (Probably me, and probably so long ago I've forgotten what it was.)

Comment: Well, color me jealous! It definitely doesn't do that for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also creating a bridge to connect channels between the two teams using Sameroom.io

Using this approach you'll only need to sign into one team and all messages posted in the connected channels will be copied across both teams.

Comment: Yeah, https://sameroom.io/pricing Not needed to just view multiple Slack channels; see [Adi's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/836570/being-in-multiple-slack-teams-simultaneously/872452#872452) and [dudewad's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/836570/being-in-multiple-slack-teams-simultaneously/925425#925425).

Comment: Sameroom is not really for being in multiple teams at the same time, since it's not going to sync all your channels, private groups, and DMs—it'll only going to sync the ones you specify.     
   
It's a decent solution if you're working with another team and don't want to deal with guest access or switching between teams. Also, it's a way to ensure all the chat history from a specific channel is stored in your own team.   
   
You can also connect to groups/contacts other platforms, like Skype, Hangouts, Gitter, etc if the other side isn't using Slack for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows App, You can sign into another team simultanously by the following way:

Click on Window >> Sign in to another team.

There you enter your details and you will be logged into multiple teams at once.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

On the top left corner in the current team you are on, click on the arrow and then "**Sign in to another workspace**"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this and because I need visual cues I have found that using a browser to access instead of the native app can work better.
You can have multiple browser windows open and resized to your preference which you can't do with the native app, at least on OSX for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying out a new method to isolate Slack teams to their own apps, using [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) to wrap Slack's web app up as separate native macOS apps.

Setup is really easy.

1. Install and run [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/)
2. In the prompt, add the URL and name for your Slack team
3. Tweak location, icon (or do that later)
4. Click Create

[image: Fluid app setup]

Rinse and repeat for any other Slack teams you want in their own app.  I really like being able to alt-tab between teams, and it works great with a multi-desktop setup.

(I have no affiliation with Fluid.  It's neat.)

Comment: One limitation of the "wrapped" web app vs. the official native app  – you can't copy-paste images directly into messages :(

Answer (score -2):

If you're using the Mac app, find the application in the filesystem, duplicate and rename it as many times as you want, then you can launch multiple apps and sign into each with a different team account. This also works if you'd like to have multiple channels open at the same time. :)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Just open Slack in a browser...